# BizTalk SFTP Adapter Port number limitations

Tags: sftp, biztalk, biztalk-2016

Are anyone aware of some limitations on BizTalk side, regarding port configurations for SFTP?

I had to connect to a server on port 53022, but I looks like BizTalk does not accept any port over than 33000 throwing “Port number cannot be negative” exception.

PS: I'm using BizTalk 2016.

Comment: No, I haven't come across that one, nor could I find any posts about it.

Comment: How are you specifying the alternate port?